# Casting of SitecoreContext vs SitecoreService Which is fast?

Tags: glass-mapper, performance-optimization

In my project I am using following code to cast items.

After some time, I came to know there are two way we can cast using SitecoreService and using glass mapper Sitecore Context.

```
results.Select(p => SitecoreContext.Cast<PageModel>(p.GetItem(), false, false)).ToList()
```

Please guide me which is fastest if i am converting more than 50 items

Answer (score 2):

They are one and the same. [`SitecoreContext`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/SitecoreContext.cs) inherits from [`AbstractSitecoreContext`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/AbstractSitecoreContext.cs) which inherits from [`SitecoreService`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/SitecoreService.cs).

If you look at the source code for the latter, you'll see that a call to `Cast<T>` as in your sample initiates a sequence of calls which eventually leads to an implementation with the following signature:

```
public object CreateType(Type type, Item item, bool isLazy,
    bool inferType, Dictionary<string, object> parameters,
    params object[] constructorParameters)
```

Therefore, for optimal performance, your best bet could be to invoke this method directly. I'm not sure how much of a performance difference it will make, however.

If you look at that method's implementation, you can see that it calls `InstantiateObject` (from the base class [`AbstractService`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper/AbstractService.cs)). If you are casting your objects in a loop, you should get a good performance improvement by calling that method directly and reusing the same instance of `SitecoreTypeCreationContext`.

Then again, if you need to cast that many items, it's possible that the design needs to be revisited... but hard to say without more information.